# What is the hash for Utilman.exe

Tags: windows-8.1, hashing, system-file

I've a Windows 8.1 machine, and have accidentally deleted Utilman.exe. I would like to know the **EXACT** SHA-256 hash of this version of the file. (64-bit OS, x64 processor, Windows 8.1) If there's anymore information that you need to know, please ask. Thanks.

Comment: Based on numerous factors the hash of this file could change (if it were patched).  You have not supplied enough information to answer your question

Comment: Can you tell me most causes for it to change?

Comment: That file could have multiple versions if it were ever patched.  Don’t download the file, extract the file yourself by installing Windows 8.1 to a VM, that has the same cumulative patches your physical install has installed

Comment: Shouldn't `sfc /scannow` restore the missing file in exactly required version?

Comment: @gronostaj Thanks, that helped! I was thinking of downloading one from exefiles.com and checking the hash, because obvious reasons. But I completely forgot about `sfc /scannow`! Now, would it make sense to close this question?

Comment: I have posted an answer. You can accept it to mark the question as solved for others who may face the same problem.

Comment: @facepalm42 **Do Not Trust** that particular website.  **The files on that website are not legitimate.**

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, because that is why I was wanting to check the hash. And a **strong** hash, so they can't have collisions.

Comment: Given Windows has a utility that will extract the correct file from the image that exists on your system you don't need to download executables like Utilman.exe from hostile malicious websites like the one you linked too.

Comment: I knew it was a fake website, I was just curious if it was actually the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/267029). Instead asking for a solution to your problem, you're asking for implementation of your solution, which is wrong.

You can simply run `sfc /scannow` to restore the missing file.